# jquery sortable on phone tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm using [johnny/jquery-sortable](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable) and it doesn't work on phone. There will be some problem with touch events but i don't know where. My code looks like:

```
$('.sortableTBody').sortable({
        handle: 'td.sortableTd',
        event: 'touch',
        helper: 'clone',
        itemSelector: 'tr',
        placeholder: '<tr class="sortablePlaceholder"><th></th><th class="short">drop there</th><th></th><th></th>',
        onDrop: function ($placeholder, container, $closestItemOrContainer) {
            var data = $('.sortableTBody').sortable("serialize").toArray();
            var jsonString =JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');
            $.nette.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: {link sort!},
                data: {'data': jsonString}
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with touchpunch, here is the link:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.